# Test names in Go coverage profile

Tags: go, testing, code-coverage

As it stands, `go test` coverage profiles can indicate the number of times a statement ran, but not the tests that ran it.

The way I see it, there are three potential solutions, in order of preference:

1. A third-party tool. Unfortunately, I have been unable to find one. I thought [go-acc](https://github.com/ory/go-acc) would have what I need, but it doesn't.
2. Modifying the Go source code. I have found my way to [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.4:src/cmd/go/internal/load/test.go), which I believe is the closest I've been to the point where the counters are modified. However, the relevant code is in a template, which makes it very hard to navigate.
3. A manual solution, like running coverage with individual tests and checking the relevant statement.

Is there anything I've missed? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Run just the one test you are interested in.

Comment: I'm not sure this is realistically feasible, that's not what a coverage profile does. A coverage profile indicates *if* a line of code is covered by tests. What you're asking for goes from a boolean value per line to (at minimum) a slice of strings per line, which is an order of magnitude more complex and multiple orders more raw data.

Comment: Hi @Adrian. Yeah, this would be a lot more data (not sure it would take more time), but it would be handy for what I'm trying to do now.